# SQL COUNT of COUNT

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, group-by

I have some data I am querying. The table is composed of two columns - a unique ID, and a value. I would like to count the number of times each unique value appears (which can easily be done with a COUNT and GROUP BY), but I then want to be able to count that. So, I would like to see how many items appear twice, three times, etc.

So for the following data (`ID`, `val`)...

> 1, 2
>   2, 2
>   3, 1
>   4, 2
>   5, 1
>   6, 7
>   7, 1

The intermediate step would be (`val`, `count`)...

> 1, 3
>   2, 3
>   7, 1

And I would like to have (`count_from_above`, `new_count`)...

> 3, 2  -- since three appears twice in the previous table
>   1, 1  -- since one appears once in the previous table

Is there any query which can do that? If it helps, I'm working with Postgres. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
select
   times,
   count(1)
from ( select 
          id,
          count(distinct value) as times
       from table
       group by id ) a
group by times
```